# Controller Mapping is not working in a spring multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating a multi-module project in a spring boot application and have an internal library which is created for all the common services,repository etc.
Then I have added this internal library as a dependency to the parent project .

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.testlab.internal"})
public class ProfileServiceApplication {
  @LoadBalanced
  @Bean
  RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      return new RestTemplate();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ProfileServiceApplication.class , args);
  }
}
```

Now after this change all the controller mapping stopped working, i.e 
spring is not able find the handle method for any mapping .

But after adding a test controller in the **ProfileServiceApplication** class it worked seamlessly .

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.testlab.internal"})
public class ProfileServiceApplication {

  @LoadBalanced
  @Bean
  RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      return new RestTemplate();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ProfileServiceApplication.class , args);
  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String home() {
      return "hello";
  }
}
```

This is working.

And my controller looks like this.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class PringConversationController {
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public String home() {
      return "hello";
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: how does your controller look like? is it also inside "internal library"?

Comment: The controller in not in the internal library.Also I have updated my controller in the post. @VladMamaev

Comment: what if you set the other annotations (`@Slf4j`, 
`@RestController`) in the main included version as well?

Comment: We can do that ,but will that help? I mean is there any specific reason you are suggesting that